# Query for last document with different restriction per document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a list of cars in the following form:

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("60a2c0621e5f043b735e36ef"),
    "car_id": 78,
    "terminal": "JFK",
    "timestamp": ISODate("2020-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"),
    
  },
```

I wish to create a query where there are 2 restrictions per car (`car_id` and `timestamp`). Both parameters (`car_id` and `timestamp`) are different per each car.

Example:

- for `car_id` '78" get the last document where the `timestamp` is
  "2020-02-15T05:00:11.000Z"
- for `car_id` "79" get the last document
  where the `timestamp` is "2020-02-23T11:07:27.000Z"

I managed to get it per one car but not for each car.

My expected result would be:

```
car_id   timestamp                terminal
78       2020-02-08T17:00:00Z     LAX
79       2020-02-11T17:00:00Z     MIA
```

**[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D2YedLrhjY3)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just need to sort before `$group` stage,

- `$sort` by timestamp in ascending order

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "car_id": 78,
          "timestamp": {
            "$lte": ISODate("2020-02-15T05:00:11.000Z")
          }
        },
        {
          "car_id": 79,
          "timestamp": {
            "$lte": ISODate("2020-02-23T11:07:27.000Z")
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { "$sort": { "timestamp": 1 } },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$car_id",
      "last": { "$last": "$$ROOT" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yLbnZoqv0KU)

> Simplified the `$match` stage condition, it will work same as your syntax.